# Redirect a soap request to another soap service without sending a 302 to client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, spring-ws

There are two existing web services, a soap service and a rest service running on a production environment. Now I am supposed to write a new proxy service (to be deployed separately on tomcat) which will handle all the incoming requests for both SOAP and REST (GET/PUT/POST/DELETE) services and based on some logic it will modify and route the requests to the REST service. However for the SOAP web service, it should blindly tunnel the request to the existing SOAP service. The only catch in this overall implementation is that the client applications which call this new proxy service cannot know that it is redirecting the requests internally.

I'm not sure on how to best implement the tunneling for SAOP service requests, and so far the options I've explored are -

- Use the Tuckey URLRewrite filter, which won't work because it will send the client a 302
- Write my own servlet which will open a new connection for each request which will hide the redirect from the client. This will work, however it doesn't seem like a clean/scalable approach. Presuming this service will be under heavy load.

Is there any better way of doing this? I'd really appreciate any useful inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it dependents on how the client handle the response message.
If you use camel-cxf endpint to proxy the SOAP request, I think you don't need to worry about 302 response, as the CXF client can take care of it out of box.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was traveling. Unfortunately, clients are not written by us, they are all 3rd party implementations, so I don't think I can rely on camel-cxf. The only option which might work is the 2nd one as mentioned in my question. Planning to proceed with that.